# Continuous Integration with BitBucket

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, maven-3, artifactory, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm developing a private webapp in JSF which is available over the internet and now reached a stage where I wanted to introduce CI (Which I'm fairly new to) into the whole process. My current project setup looks like this:

- **myApp-persistence:** maven project that handles DB access (DAOs and hibernate stuff)
- **myApp-core:** maven project, that includes all the Java code (Beans and Utils). It has a dependency on myApp-persistence.jar
- **myApp-a:** maven project just with frontend code (xhtml, css, JS). Has a dependency on myApp-core.jar
- **myApp-b:** maven project just with frontend code (xhtml, css, JS). Has a dependency on myApp-core.jar

myApp-a and myApp-b are independent from each other, they are just different instances of the core for two different platforms and only display certain components differently or call different bean-methods.

Currently I'm deploying manually, i.e. use the eclipse built-in export as war function and then manually upload it to the deployments dir of my wildfly server on prod. I'm using BitBucket for versioning control and just recently discovered pipelines in BitBucket and implemented one for each repository (every project is a separate repo). Now myApp-persistence builds perfectly fine because all dependencies are accessible via the public maven repo but myApp-core (hence myApp-a and myApp-b, too) fails of course because myApp-persistence isn't published on the central maven repo.

1. **Is it possible to tell BitBucket somehow to use the myApp-persistence.jar in the corresponding repo on BitBucket?**
2. **If yes, how? And can I also tell BitBucket to deploy directly to prod in case the build including tests ran fine?**
3. **If no, what would be a best practice to do that? I was thinking of using a second dev server (already available, so no big deal) as a CI server but then still I would need some advise or recommendations on which tools (Jenkins, artifactory, etc.) to use.**

One important note maybe: I'm the only person working on this project so this might seem like an overkill but for me the process of setting that up is quite some valuable experience. That said, I'm not necessarily looking for the quickest solution but for the most professional and convenient solution.

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view, you can find the solution in this post-https://christiangalsterer.wordpress.com/2015/04/23/continuous-integration-for-pull-requests-with-jenkins-and-stash/. It guides you step by step how to set up everything. The post is from 2015 but the process and idea are still the same. Hope it helps.